# How do I run cassandra-stress against AWS Keyspaces with Sigv4 authentication?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-keyspaces, cassandra-stress-tool

I want to use Cassandra-stress tool to load test on AWS keyspaces but can't figure out how to use sigv4authprovider. Can someone please help with the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is helping, but you can define a service account with classic authentication (login, password) against keyspaces. This is the best way to test cassandra tools/libs compatibility. SIGV4 would require some extra work with actually overwriting the way said libs/tools create their connection.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/programmatic.credentials.ssc.html